# Quick SQL question! Sort by most occurences of an attribute

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables as such:

Categories:
ID - Name - Desc

Items
ID - Name - CategoryID - Desc - Price

I want a query that returns a list of categories ranked by the most occurences in the items table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Name, count(i.ID)
FROM Categories c
LEFT JOIN Items i on (c.ID=i.CategoryID)
GROUP BY c.ID
ORDER BY count(i.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  CategoryID, count(*)
FROM 
  items
GROUP BY 
  CategoryID
ORDER BY 
  2 DESC
```

You can then join to categories to get their names.